# Maintaining two very close but separate lines of development under svn?

Tags: svn, version-control, release-management

We have our project under svn and everything is going all and well. Recently a major customer asked us to do some quite specific customizations for them that requires coding and stuff (could not be done using configuration or deployment). We decided to maintain two separate lines of development:

- The `trunk` branch is our standard version that is deployed for
  ordinary customers
- The `arsh` branch is for this customer and is under ongoing development separate from what is  going on in the `trunk`

Now the thing is `arsh` should countinually receive updates from `trunk` and sometimes features implemented in `arsh` are useful in the `trunk`. The relation is kinda bi-directional but one direction is quite prevalent (from `trunk` to `arsh`) but the other one is occasional.

What would be the best way to do this ? work-flows ? best practices ? insights ?

EDIT : We use PHP 5.3, MySQL, Apache and Linux.

Answer (score 3):

Best practice? `#ifdef` (or separate implementations of the same interface conditionally included or conditionally dependency-injected by runtime configuration or any other compile-time or run-time conditional)!

Maintaining parallel versions as branches is pain in any version control system. Parallel versions are best maintained using appropriate conditional compilation or runtime configuration technique.

Remember, if you merge a branch A to branch B and than branch B back to branch A, both branches will be exactly identical. This is intrinsic property of 3-way merge. It is exactly what you want for feature branches, but it is totally unsuitable for maintaining parallel versions for different customers.

For keeping versions for different customers instead use conditional compilation.

- In object oriented code, you can usually have base class with the common logic and per-variant custom derived class with just the logic specific to that variant that is either conditionally included in project or conditionally instantiated.
- Most programming languages support some form of conditional compilation, Java being notable exception.

This approach allows everybody to always immediately check that they didn't break any feature for either variant, either by running tests for all variants or having all variants built and tested by continuous integration server.

You mention PHP. There is no compilation step there, so the configuration will be just runtime. I'd probably create a directory with customer-specific overrides that would conditionally get included in appropriate templates.

Note: I am currently working on a C++ project which is customized for over 20 customers in this manner and it scales just fine. We don't have exactly code per customer, instead we have a set of features that are optional and different subsets are shipped to different customers. That makes it a bit easier to test all features, because we can build a maximal variant and test that. That helps when you grow to large number of features, especially if your project takes a long time to build (our continuous integration build runs about an hour, nightly build 8 hours and building all customer variants takes more than whole day).

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention your language, but assuming you're using an object-oriented language, think about keeping your custom functionality in separate implementations of the same interface and/or base class, and use a factory at runtime to decide which implementation to run. For example (in C#):

```
public interface IProcessor {
    void ProcessFile(string fileName);
}

public abstract class BaseProcessor : IProcessor {
    void IProcessor.ProcessFile(string fileName) {

        // Do shared stuff here like logging, validation, etc.

        ProcessFileForClient(fileName);
    }
    protected abstract void ProcessFileForClient(string fileName);
}

public class NormalProcessor : BaseProcessor {
    protected override void ProcessFileForClient(string fileName) {
        // Do your normal routine here
    }
}

public class AcmeProcessor : BaseProcessor {
    protected override void ProcessFileForClient(string fileName) {
        // Do your custom stuff here
    }
}

// This can be as complex as you need - you should probably use an IoC/DI framework,
// but this is a simple example.
public static class ProcessorFactory {
    public static IProcessor GetProcessor(string clientCode) {
        switch (clientCode) {
            case "Acme": return new AcmeProcessor();
            default: return new NormalProcessor();
        }
    }
}
```

This method has the benefit of keeping your custom code out of the way of your normal code, while still allowing you to share as much as you'd like in that base class.

Comment: As long as you can ship separate builds to separate customers, I'd prefer only compiling in the appropriate implementation in the code. I.e. multiple implementations under the same name, conditionally included in the project. C# also has conditional compilation, which is most appropriate if the differences are small.

Comment: @JanHudec Very true - I suppose it just depends on the environment. If you're dealing with a web- or service-based application, it doesn't really matter. But a packaged product, your conditional compilation would probably be the better option.